# Nokogiri parse all a href elements of certain class

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have the following site I am trying to parse with nokogiri:

```
 <section
id="em_widget-6" class="widget widget_em_widget"><ul><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/pale-seas/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Pale Seas &#8211; verlegt!</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">09_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/PALE-SEAS-_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/banfi/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Banfi</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">13_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/banfi_press_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/2908/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Kiez Treats &#8211; Binkbeats</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">15_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/binkbeats_press_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/mynth/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Mynth</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">16_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/de-0419-826366-back.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/noah-gundersen/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Noah Gundersen</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">17_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/noah_gundersen_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/garden-city-movement/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Garden City Movement &#8211; verlegt!!!</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">19_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/Garden-City-Movement_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/trails/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Trails</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">21_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/TRAILS_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/james-chatburn-wayne-snow/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>James Chatburn &#038; Wayne Snow</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">22_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/chatburn_snow_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/amy-shark/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Amy Shark &#8211; AUSVERKAUFT!</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">26_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/AmyShark_Pressshot12018_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/hippie-sabotage/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Hippie Sabotage</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">27_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/Hippiesabotage_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/me-reas/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Me &#038; Reas</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">28_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/Me-Reas_1_©-David-Häuser_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/projectbeatmaker-spring-session/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Project:Beatmaker &#8211; Spring Session</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">30_März | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Club</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/projectbeatmaker_logo.png" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/kiez-treats-peter-broderick/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Kiez Treats &#8211; Peter Broderick</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">12_April | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/Peter-7-by-Declan-Kelly_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/holly-miranda/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Holly Miranda</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">13_April | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/holly-miranda-750_0.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/glode/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Gløde</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">14_April | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/BY-JULIEN-FERTL2_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/this-is-the-kit/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>This Is The Kit</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">20_April | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/thisisthekit_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event"><a
href="https://www.haekken.de/events/marvin-brooks/" class="event-link"><div
class="event-info"><div><h2><span>Marvin Brooks</span></h2><p
class="event-meta">21_April | <span
style="text-transform: uppercase;">Live</span></p></div></div><img
src="https://www.haekken.de/wp-content/uploads/Marvin-Brooks1_NICULAI_CONSTANTINESCU_PHOTOGRAPY_online.jpg" alt="Event-Foto"/></a></li><li
class="haekken-event">
```

I am trying to parse all the links with this code but simply get an empty array:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.haekken.de/events/"))  


page.css("a.event-link").each do |n|
    puts n["href"]
end

puts page.class   # => Nokogiri::HTML::Document
```

when using this selector on for example https://try.jsoup.org/ I get all the correct elements that I want to extract from this page. Do I need to loop through all these elements or is there a simpler way to extract all the links from the `<a>` elements?

Comment: Check the URL, I see no links with class `.event-link` at the address you opened with Nokogiri. There's no issue with the code itself, it should work.

Comment: as bartosz said, couldn't find the same markup as you had. For the page I can see, ` page.css('.entry-title a[rel="bookmark"]').each { |n| puts n['href'] }` shows the relevant links.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments: URL was wrong and code was working (for future googelers)

Sorry I could not use any of your answers as the correct one (since they where comments)